# Does uploading VHD file require another license or can I use the on-premises license keys?

Tags: azure

I have no software assurance nor license portability and I'm looking to upload activated VHD file. How will the license affect uploaded images in Azure? Does it require another license or can I use the on-premises license keys?

Answer (score 0):

> How will the license affect uploaded images in Azure?

License will not affect upload images to Azure.

But when you try to create Azure VM with that image, you need to buy license from Azure or you need enter your license key in new VM.

When you create Azure VM, you will see this settings:

[image]

> Can I move Windows Server 2012 licenses and images between Hyper-V and
>   Azure? The license to run Windows Server in the Azure environment is
>   by default included in the per-minute cost of your Windows Virtual
>   Machine.
>
> Windows Server licenses are not eligible for License Mobility through
>   Software Assurance, but customers licensing Windows Server with
>   Software Assurance can utilize the Azure Hybrid Benefit for a cheaper
>   per-minute cost when running a Windows Virtual Machine.
>
> Licenses for use of Windows Server on-premises (whether in a virtual
>   hard disk (VHD) or otherwise) must be obtained separately through
>   volume licensing.

More information about Azure VM licensing FAQ, please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/).